# Indexing document files

Tags: sql-server, search, indexing

I want to store and index document files like .doc, .pdf, .txt and than search this files over a basic web application and let users to download them.

I have found 2 ways. First one is store these files in MSSQL (filestream) and search them with the power of full-text search but this way is scared me because the backup file will be getting bigger and bigger. Second one is indexing these files with Windows Search Service and search them with remote query but this way lacks of full-text search power.

What is the best way to do this, is there any better alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: full text search option would be good for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process the build in functionality for fulltext search or build your own index. I would recommend building your own one as an [Inverted Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) for document search capabilities. A quite similar question was asked here: [Building Big Search Egnine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17779/recommendations-for-building-a-big-search-engine/17793#17793). Hopefully it helps you to further design what you want.